# Regular expression in C#

Tags: c#

I want to parse the second div from the following HTML:

```
<div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg><div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-7494158715135407463' itemprop='articleBody'><div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg>
```

i.e., this value: `<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-7494158715135407463' itemprop='articleBody'>`

The id can contain any numbers.

Here is what I am trying:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"'post-body-\d*'");
var res = rgx.Replace("<div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg><div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-7494158715135407463' itemprop='articleBody'><div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg>", "");
```

I expect the result `<div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg><div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg>` but that is not what I am getting.

Comment: Try using a library to parse HTML, regular expressions with HTML are inadvisable. Try htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @James - *very* inadvisable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: please help urself by writing proper question...seems like ur confused about what u need 2 do..

Comment: The result will be `"<div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg><div class='post-body entry-content' id= itemprop='articleBody'><div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg>"`.

Comment: Are you trying to **retrieve** the inner `<div>`, or **remove** it?  Your question states that you want to "parse" it, but your sample code is actually trying to remove it and retrieve the remainder.

Comment: @JonSenchyna seems like he doesn't bother now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't get your expected result is that your regex string is only searching for `'post-body-\d*'`, but not the rest of the `div` tag.  In addition, performing [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) actually replaces the text that you are searching for, rather than returning it, so you will end up getting everything *but* the text you are searching for.

Try replacing your regex string with @`"<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-\d*' itemprop='articleBody'>"` using [Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3) (or [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c) if you only care about the first occurrence), and processing the [Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match).

For example:

```
string htmlText = @"<div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg><div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-7494158715135407463' itemprop='articleBody'><div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg>";

Regex rgx = new Regex(@`"<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-\d*' itemprop='articleBody'>");
foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(htmlText))
{
    // Process matches
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% certain that the text before and after the number will always be the same, you could use the .IndexOf and .Substring methods of the String class to break-down the string in pieces.

```
string original = @"<div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg><div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-7494158715135407463' itemprop='articleBody'><div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg>"

// IndexOf returns the position in the string where the piece we are looking for starts
int startIndex = original.IndexOf(@"<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-");
// For the endIndex, add the number of characters in the string that you are looking for
int endIndex = original.IndexOf(@"' itemprop='articleBody'>") + 25;

// this substring will retrieve just the inner part that you are looking for
string newString = original.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

// newString should now equal "<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-7494158715135407463' itemprop='articleBody'>"


// or, if you want to just remove the inner part, build a different string like this:
// First, get everything leading up to the startIndex
string divString = original.Substring(0, startIndex);
// then, add everything after the endIndex
divString += original.Substring(endIndex);

// divString should now equal "<div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg><div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg>"
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your HTML fragment into an XML fragment and pull out the `id` attribute directly e.g.

```
var html = "<div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg><div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-7494158715135407463' itemprop='articleBody'><div kubedfiuabefiudsabiubfg>"
var data = XElement.Parse(html).Element("div").Attribute("id");
```